# Do you know alternative at httpruntime tag in asp.net web application for bigger request length at server?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem with request at server for send and receive data from database but without a `httpruntime` tag I don't do this, I need a alternative to this tag.

Comment: Can you please better explain your problem? So it is hard to help you.

Comment: Please provide examples of what you are trying to do. Httpruntime usually works fine. I think you might be looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3853785), but can't tell for sure.